# I am trying to locate the calender but always says that element not found. how to locate this calender please guide me

Tags: selenium

```
enter code here:
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\selenium setup\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver d= new ChromeDriver();
    
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    d.get("https://www.sarasotasheriff.org/arrest-reports/index.php");
    WebElement date = d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"));
    String dateVal = "14082020";
    
    
}
public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver d, WebElement element, String dateVal)
{
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
     js.executeScript("argument[0].setAttributr('value','"+dateVal+"');", element);
}
```

}

output:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-UNJ7VIR', ip: '192.168.43.183', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Comment: It will help us to make you resolved if you paste the Html DOM code

Comment: Thanks for reply got my solution ..it was an iframe so i need to switch to i frame and find that element this is how i got solution.